# How to logoff user while the user's session is locked

Tags: c#, logoff

I'm developing an application to run in the background for capturing a user's activity on their system, like logoff/shutdown/idle/switch user/continues press of any key/system lock etc.

It's working fine and I am able to track all activities, now I need to log off the user automatically after 15 min of system lock.

I have tried the code below. The `ExitWindowsEx()` function is working fine when user is logged in but not working after the user has locked their system.

## Used code

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags, uint dwReason);

private SessionSwitchEventHandler sseh;

void SysEventsCheck(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Reason)
    {
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
           if(condition)
           {
               ExitWindowsEx(0, 0);
           }
           break;
    }    
}
```

Can any one help me how to log off the user when he/she is in locked state.

Comment: Can't this be done in Group Policy or AD account setup?  Might not need to program anything (assuming this is a domain)

Comment: How about using this http://www.windows-commandline.com/windows-logoff-command-line/

Comment: Tried `Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /t 0");` and `Process.Start("shutdown", "-L /t 0");` but not working in locked state.

Comment: Yes we can do it by Group Policy, but we need to done it from application end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an alternative to the problem,

## Code

```
public static bool _IsLocked;
private SessionSwitchEventHandler sseh;

void SysEventsCheck(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Reason)
    {
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
            if (!_IsLocked)
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /f /t 900");
            }
            _IsLocked = true;
            break;
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
            if (_IsLocked)
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown", "-a");
            }
            _IsLocked = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Above code will schedule system restart (15 min) at the time of system locking, if user unlock system before 15 min code will cancel that schedule otherwise this will restart system after 15 min.

## Restart Scheduler code

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "/r /f /t 900");
```

## Cancel Restart

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "-a");
```